# How to override NullReferenceException behavior for a better more informative error?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono

### Context

In Unity, NullReferenceException to only logs an error and does not kick the IDE into debug mode. It's sometimes difficult for games to recreate the same environment for bugs to happen 100% of the time.

Component variables are serialized and exposed through the unity editor and designers often forget to assign values, causing this situation where the member variable of the component is NULL.

NullReferenceException being the most common exception because of the special situation of Unity, I'm trying to explore ways to make the exception more apparent right off the bat.

### Question

NullReferenceException messages are super unhelpful. For me, when I see a NullReferenceException I don't even know which variable is NULL.

---

```
player.GetComponent<Movement>().AnothingVariable.CallFunction() // NullReferenceException, which part caused it?
```

Current Error Message:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Ideal Error Message:

```
NullReferenceException: Trying to access CallFunction in type Movement, in GameObject "Player" from component "Controller".
```

Comment: For me, the mouse tells me which var is null

Comment: what do you mean by "the mouse"?

Comment: NullReferenceException should be debugged. In debug mode, you can easily tell what variable is null.

Comment: In unity, NullReferenceException to just logs an error. It doesn't kick the IDE into debug mode. Also in games, it's very difficult to recreate the same environment for bugs to happen 100% of the time.

Comment: First of all your example smells of feature envy. Secondly, you should decide whenever null reference is valid or not. If it is not valid you are probably missing null check with argumentnullexception in constructor, if it is valid and you are fine with nothing happening you should add Null-conditional operators, or return own NullObject instead of null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the exceptions are not helpfull, that usually means you have too many commands in one line. A simple solution is to split the code over more lines, using temporary variables to store the result of each and every member call (function, property or field).

That will likely **not** be a performance penalty. The compiler and JiT Compiler should be able to notice that those variables are largely "useless" and cut them out during release builds. You get better read and debugable code, with little to no penalties.

Comment: You can also do this *purely* for debug purposes. E.g. an NPE occurred, so you put a `Debug(player.GetComponent<Movement>())` on the previous line. If that line throws an NPE, it's `player` that's null. If it prints "null" there you go. If it's fine, then it's `Movement#AnothingVariable` that's null.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you can't change this. 
If you are accessing a property of an object and it has the potential to to be null you should null check it. You could  use the the new null checking features of the more modern versions of C#

```
A?.B?.C?.D
```

If A or B or C is null that expression returns null and you don't get the exception. However you don't get the info on what was null. To my knowledge the only way to do that is to explicitly check the arguments and throw your own exceptions (if that's what you want to happen).

```
if (a == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("a");
}
```

Etc for B and C

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to work out what is `null`, a better strategy is to defensively program against this situation. The approach that is commonly in use is to use *guard clauses* to ensure that there is no possibility of the variable ever being `null`.

### Instantiation

A guard clause can be added to an object's constructor to ensure fields cannot ever contain `null`.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    // Marking fields readonly ensures they cannot be set
    // (thus cannot be set to null) from anywhere outside 
    // of the constructor
    public readonly string field1;
    public readonly Type field2;

    public SomeClass(string field1, Type field2)
    {
        // Throwing ArgumentNullException ensures the class
        // can never be created with missing (null) values.
        if (field1 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(field1));
        if (field2 == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(field2));

        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public string Field1
    {
        get { return field1; } // Never null
    }

    public Type Field2
    {
        get { return field2; } // Never null
    }
}
```

### Method Calls

Guard clauses can also be used to ensure method parameters are not null so you don't end up with nasty NullRefereneceExceptions.

```
public void DoSomething(string param1, Type param2)
{
    if (param1 == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(param1));
    if (param2 == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(param2));

    // param1 and param2 can now be used safely because they cannot be null
}
```

It is not *always* practical to use guard clauses, but you *should* do it everywhere a `null` is not useful to the program to prevent having to add `null` checking logic everywhere.

In cases where `null` is meaningful to the program (as Dave also mentioned), you will need to explicitly check to prevent it.

```
if (variable != null && variable.Field != null)
{
    // Do something with variable.Field
    var foo = variable.Field;
}
```

Or

```
var foo = variable?.Field;
```

### Null Object Pattern

Finally, if a program requires a reference to be `null` a better approach than explicitly checking everywhere is to make a concrete object to *represent* `null` rather than actually using a `null` object pointer. This is known as the [Null Object Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object).

```
public interface IService
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class NullService : IService
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do nothing at all to represent a no-op
    }
}

public class MyService : IService
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something interesting
        Console.WriteLine("Something was done.");
    }
}
```

Then, in the program, you can have a `MyService` instance to represent a real value, or a `NullService` to represent `null`.

```
IService service1 = new MyService();
IService service2 = new NullService();

service1.DoSomething();
service2.DoSomething(); // Doesn't throw NullReferenceException
```